# Facebook Like generates tons of pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've got a page with list of elements that link to subsites. Each of the element got a like button. Somehow after liking an element it generates on my FB account a page entry ( left menu on FB account - the older view not the timeline one ) Got no idea why this is happening and I assume this should not work that way.

I use xfbml for the like buttons.

Whats more strange is that I deleted all admin and app_id referals so I do not get spammed with new entrys but still after liking an element it generates an entry on my FB.

Ill add some code that I have on my site

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And the fb button code

```
<fb:like href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>details/<?php echo $id ?>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Each of the subsites have a different meta tags like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Whatever" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>details/<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/layout/logo_mini.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Whatever" />
```

And here is a link to a picture http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/5733/problemxv.jpg

To clarify what I mean. I got multiple likes, first like click on the element generates another page which is show in the red circled area on my FB account. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the og:type shouldn't be "website" but should more accurately reflect the entity being "liked" (e.g. "article", "video", any other [built-in object type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/), [your you can create your own](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/))

For Open Graph objects with the "website" type, Facebook creates the pages you are talking about.